# Is $C^{\infty}_c(R^n) $ dense in $C_0(R^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $C^{\infty}_c(R^n) $ is dense in $L^p(R^n)$ then is it dense in $C_0(R^n)$?

Comment: $L^p$ is not contained in $C_o$... nor vice-versa... Are you asking the precise question you intend?

Comment: if $C^{\infty}_c(R^n) $  is dense in $C_0(R^n)$.Do you know a proof?

Comment: The density of test functions in many (not all!) natural function spaces on manifolds, etc., is a very standard thing. There are several proofs, and these can be found in standard texts, and on-line notes, such as in various of my own (e.g., functional analysis at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/). Density _fails_ for bounded continuous functions with sup norm, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question if $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$. Yes, it is. Either one uses cut-off functions as in the other answer or one can just use the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version) (actually the version for $C_0$-spaces):

So notice that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is clearly a subalgebra of $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$. Moreover, it can be seen easily by considering bump-functions that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ seperates the points, i.e., for all $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$, $x \neq y$ there is $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Finally, by considering bump-functions one see that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ vanishes nowhere, which means that for each $x \in \mathbb R^n$ there is $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$.

Hence, the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem yields the density of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is true. First, note that you can use convolution to find smooth functions arbitrarily similar to a given continuous function. You can do this by covering the space will balls, smoothing on each ball, and stitching them back together with a partition of unity. For this reason, it should be enough to prove that smooth compactly supported functions are dense in *smooth* and vanishing at infinity functions. This is just an easy cut-off argument though.

Let $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a function $g$ with compact support so that $||f-g||_\infty < \epsilon$, since the topology on $C_0$ is the uniform topology induced by the uniform norm.

But now let $\epsilon$ be given. Then there is some compact set $K_\epsilon$ outside of which we have $|f|<\epsilon$. Let $B_n$ be the smallest ball of integer radius (just for simplicity) containing $K$, and let $\phi_n$ be a smooth cut-off function which is $1$ on $B_n$ and $0$ for $|x| > n+1$. Then we can define $g = |f|\phi_n$. On $K_\epsilon$, $f$ and $g$ are identical. And outside $K_\epsilon$, they differ by at most $\epsilon$. Yet $g$ has compact support.